# Quantum ESPRESSO vs AMS

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, computational-chemistry, software-recommendations, electronic-transport

Both Quantum ESPRESSO and AMS (Amsterdam Modeling Suite) can be used to perform simulations of the materials and their properties. What are the differences between AMS and Quantum ESPRESSO? Is it accurate to say that one of them is better than the other? Can one of them be used to simulate systems that the other can not? Any answer is greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Sorry that no one welcomed you earlier, but I wonder if you have figured out the answer to this question now, or if you are still actively seeking an answer for it?